# Grant on constant value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

On schema  **test**  package  **pkg_test** I have **c_status CONSTANT NUMBER := 1;**

How add grant on this value to other scheme **test2**?

Some like this:

**Grant select pkg_test.c_status  to test2**

On schema test2 I need constant value in update statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot grant single variables, only packages, procedures and functions. Would be

```
Grant execute on test.pkg_test to test2;
```

If you need to give access only to this single constant, then I would suggest

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_status RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
    return test.pkg_test.c_status;
END get_status;

GRANT EXECUTE ON get_status TO test2;
```

Or a bit more generic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_constant(const_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS

    INVALID_IDENTIFIER EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_IDENTIFIER, -904);

    res NUMBER;
BEGIN
   IF UPPER(const_name) IN ('C_STATUS') THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := test.pkg_test.'||const_name||'; END;' USING OUT res; 
      RETURN res;
   ELSE
      RAISE INVALID_IDENTIFIER;
   END IF;
END get_constant;

GRANT EXECUTE ON get_constant TO test2;
```